# Android SDK unity

Tags: android-sdk, android-ndk, unity3d-android

С новой Unity не могу понять как правильно установить Android SDK + юзать Unity 5 Remote.
Вроде я что-то устанавливал, хотя зашел в настройки и не понял установлено или нет.
Скрин ниже, пожалуйста, отпишите, установлено или нет.
1) Если установлено, то не могу понять, почему Unity пишет "Set-up Android SDK path to..." при использовании Unity 5 Remote, расскажите, как пофиксить проблему. 2) Если не установлено, то подскажите, как правильно установить.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На скрине снимите галочку Android SDK Tools Installed with Unity(Recommend), затем укажите путь где установлена ваша SDK.